# DataGrid not sorting by DESC

Tags: c#, sorting, datagrid

There is a database in Access, I get data when searching and I want to sort the result, when sorting ASC it works but nothing happens on DESC, here is the DataGrid code in MainWindow.xaml:
`<DataGrid Name="dataGrid" CanUserSortColumns="True"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="742" Margin="0,142,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1440" Sorting="dataGrid_Sorting"/>`

and this is the one that interacts with the DataGrid, with the Button_Click method, data is searched for in the database:

```
readonly string content = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\User\source\repos\CG\BaseLink.txt");
        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string searchValue = searchBox.Text; // значение поиска, введенное в поле searchBox
            OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + content + "nwind.mdb");
            connection.Open();
 
            // создаем объект OleDbCommand и выполняем параметризованный запрос
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE CustomerID LIKE ? OR CompanyName LIKE ? " +
                "OR ContactName LIKE ? OR ContactTitle LIKE ? OR Address LIKE ? OR City LIKE ? OR Region LIKE ?" +
                "OR PostalCode LIKE ? OR Country LIKE ? OR Phone LIKE ? OR Fax LIKE ?;", connection);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@searchValue1", "%" + searchValue + "%");
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@searchValue2", "%" + searchValue + "%");
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@searchValue3", "%" + searchValue + "%");
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@searchValue4", "%" + searchValue + "%");
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@searchValue5", "%" + searchValue + "%");
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@searchValue6", "%" + searchValue + "%");
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@searchValue7", "%" + searchValue + "%");
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@searchValue8", "%" + searchValue + "%");
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@searchValue9", "%" + searchValue + "%");
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@searchValue10", "%" + searchValue + "%");
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@searchValue11", "%" + searchValue + "%");
            OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);
 
            DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
            dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet, "Customers");
 
            dataGrid.ItemsSource = dataSet.Tables["Customers"].DefaultView;
            connection.Close();
 
        }
```

and here is the dataGrid_Sorting method that sorts the data:

```
private void dataGrid_Sorting(object sender, DataGridSortingEventArgs e)
        {
            DataGridColumn column = e.Column;
 
            // Определение направления сортировки
            ListSortDirection direction;
            if (column.SortDirection == null)
            {
                // Сортировка не была применена ранее - устанавливаем направление сортировки по умолчанию
                direction = ListSortDirection.Ascending;
            }
            else if (column.SortDirection == ListSortDirection.Ascending)
            {
                // Сортировка применена в направлении по возрастанию - меняем направление на убывание
                direction = ListSortDirection.Descending;
            }
            else
            {
                // Сортировка применена в направлении по убыванию - меняем направление на возрастание
                direction = ListSortDirection.Ascending;
            }
 
            // Установка направления сортировки
            column.SortDirection = direction;
 
            // Создание команды для выполнения запроса к базе данных Access
            string sortOrder = (direction == ListSortDirection.Ascending) ? "ASC" : "DESC";
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM Customers ORDER BY [" + column.SortMemberPath + "] " + sortOrder);
 
            // Выполнение запроса к базе данных Access и получение данных в виде DataTable
            DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
            using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + content + "nwind.mdb"))
            {
                connection.Open();
                command.Connection = connection;
                using (OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(command))
                {
                    adapter.Fill(dataTable);
                }
            }
 
            // Обновление источника данных ItemsSource для DataGrid
            dataGrid.ItemsSource = dataTable.DefaultView;
 
            // Обновление данных в DataGrid
            dataGrid.Items.Refresh();
        }
```

Worked with AI, this is the first project, don't hit hard, thanks for the help!

I am trying to implement sorting in a DataGrid and am looking for help in implementing this

Answer (score 0):

> To group, sort, and filter data in the DataGrid, you bind the DataGrid to an ICollectionView implementation that supports these operations.

[ICollectionView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.icollectionview?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) implements interface [INotifyCollectionChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged?view=net-7.0&viewFallbackFrom=windowsdesktop-7.0), [DataView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dataview?view=net-7.0) does not implement this interface.

[How to: Group, sort, and filter data in the DataGrid control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/how-to-group-sort-and-filter-data-in-the-datagrid-control?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8&viewFallbackFrom=netdesktop-7.0)

Answer (score 0):

if your [dataTable] variable fills with your correct Data (by order DESC) I think you need to bind your data again. something like:

```
dataGrid.Columns.Clear();
dataGrid.DataSource = dataTable;
```

but by the way, you don't need to refer to your Database again for ordering data.
you can use Sort() method to do this (dataGridView1.Sort(Column, direction)).
for more information see this link :
[learn_microsoft_com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.sortorder?view=windowsdesktop-7.0)